# snakemake - configure rules to run with local container (Singularity, Docker)

Tags: snakemake, singularity-container

For snakemakev5.27+

Is there a way to run snakemake with the container directive that points to a local image? E.g. if I store the Docker containers on Dockerhub, and I also have a copy locally, when running snakemake, I don't want the rule to pull a singularity image copy from DockerHub if there already exists the exact copy locally. Makes for faster runs.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just pass a relative or absolute file path to the directive.

Comment: could you provide an example? when I build an docker image locally it is listed with 'docker image list' but there is no file to point to.

Comment: This is about Singularity images which are simple files on the local filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the [snakemake manual](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html?highlight=containerized#containerization-of-conda-based-workflows) doesn't explicitly state it, it is possible to use a local singularity image using the `containerized` directive.

So instead of the example in the link above:

```
containerized: "docker://username/myworkflow:1.0.0"
```

You can point to the singularity sif file path (which contains the image)

```
containerized: "/path/to/myimage.sif"
```

Make sure you use `--use-singularity` when running snakemake.

**How to build the singularity (sif) image:**

You can build the sif image in various ways as described [here](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.8/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html#locally-available-images-cached-by-docker), bug as for your question, you can build it from a local docker image.

I.e. you can list your local images by `docker images` and pick one to build the local sif file like so:

```
SINGULARITY_NOHTTPS=1 singularity build /path/to/myimage.sif docker-daemon://mydockerimage:latest
```

Note, it doesn't seem to work straight from local docker container, i.e. I would have expected this to work:

```
containerized: "docker-daemon://scpipe_docker:latest"
```

... but it didn't as of snakemake version 6.10.0