# Containerization of Conda based workflows

Tags: snakemake

I am using the integrated conda package management in snakemake to supply software environments to my rules. Now, I would like to try the same with a container spawned from a docker image.

I automatically generate a Dockerfile from my workflow using (see documentation)

```
snakemake --containerize > Dockerfile
```

In the following, I am trying to use this container image in the workflow via the `containerized:` directive and `snakemake --use-singularity`. However

```
containerized: "docker://Dockerfile"
```

gives me a fail in the pull of the sigularity image. I am not sure about this syntax, has anybody used this before?

Comment: Looks like you have to build the singularity image and then can pass the .sif location to containerized: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70078830/12373791

Comment: Thank you @TroyComi, converting the Dockerfile to a .sif and passing it to the rule works like a charm!